# Passing different parameter to multiple instances of Angular components

Tags: angular

So I have created a simple Angular component `custom-component` with an input parameter and a button on click of which I am just printing the parameter value to the console

**Input parameter declaration**

```
@Input() componentType: string;
```

**Component Instance creation** -

```
<custom-component componentType="Type1"></custom-component>

<custom-component componentType="Type2"></custom-component>
```

**Button click event handler inside .ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.componentType); // console prints Type1/Type2 here
}

onButtonClicked(event: any) {
    console.log(this.componentType); // console prints Type1 always irrespective of which component is clicked
}
```

Now, my problem is irrespective of which component button I click, it always logs **Type1**.
I tried to put debug inside ngOnInit() and confirmed that the correct value is being passed during the component creation.

But, once component is created, these values are not persisted during next operation (button click in this case)

Comment: Could you please provide some more code details? click event, component.ts code etc.

Comment: Please share the code for your click event.

Comment: Updated question with the code details @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: Please assign each code block to the file. Where this handler is called?  How the compinents are presented in a view? If You add a 3ed on top with Type0, are all clicks will return Type0? Maybe 1st one is overlaping others and You are clicking only 1st one? Show the relevant view part of CustomComponent please.

Answer (score -1):

You are making a mistake on how your are passing your data to the component using Input:

```
<custom-component [componentType]="Type1"></custom-component> // this way it will pass the updated data.

<custom-component [componentType]="Type2"></custom-component>
```

Now, the other part to understand is How Lifecycles hooks works. So, `ngOnInit` is called once and updates the values which is the default one, but when you change the values based on any event like `click`, you need to implement `ngOnChanges` to get the updated values.

In Component instance :

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.componentType); // console prints the updated values over time
}
```

Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for more details.

Comment: The `componentType` is of type string so I doubd it is a mistake here as it was most probably intended (hard to imagine variables `Type1`/`Type2`). Regardless if those are strings or string variables.

Comment: FIrst of all, what ever type it is the way Input received the value is wrong, @Eatos you can check how to pass values to input secondly, his question is why he is receiving type1 because he is checking values only on 'ngOnInit'.  check how to pass data [here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/passing-data-angular-2-components-input#:~:text=The%20first%20step%20to%20passing,via%20the%20%40Input()%20decorator!)

Comment: Actually he wrote that on init "console prints Type1/Type2 here" and "confirmed that the correct value is being passed". Because he is not using one way data binding and as he is not, the part about lifecycles is irrelevant. Not saying You are not giving a good points here, just irrelevant to the given code and what he wrote.